# Iterate through a specific range of rows in java (apache poi)

Tags: java, excel

Right now I'm iterating through all rows and finding the index, then if the index is within bounds, I do something with it

```
for (Row r: sheet) {
    if(r.getRowNum()>x)
        Cell cell = r.getCell(1);
    something something something
}
```

But is there a way to iterate through a specific range without having to go through the comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `HSSFSheet` object has a `getRow(int index)` method you can use to retrieve any row.

```
for (int i=start_row; i<=end_row; i++)
{
    HSSFRow = sheet.getRow(i);
    something something something
}
```